# Symfony2: formbuilder : dynamically modify querybuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder, formbuilder

I am using the formbuilder to create a form as followed:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('content',    'textarea')
        ->add('rosters',    'entity', array( 
            'class'    =>   'PlatformBundle:team',
            'property' =>   'display',
            'multiple' =>   true,
            'expanded' =>   true,
            'required' =>   true
        ))
        ->add('send',       'submit')
    ;
}
```

At the moment I get all "teams". I need to adapt the form to display certain teams depending of the request. 
I can use the query-builder inside the form builder

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('content',    'textarea')
        ->add('rosters',    'entity', array( 
            'class'    =>   'PlatformBundle:team',
            'property' =>   'display',
            'query_builder' => function(TeamRepository $t) use ($userId) {
                return $r->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->where('(t.user = :user')
            },
            'multiple' =>   true,
            'expanded' =>   true,
            'required' =>   true
        ))
        ->add('send',       'submit')
    ;
}
```

But the query changes for different questionnaire. In brief: always the same questionnaire but different teams to be listed (Am I making sense?).

Does someone has an idea how dynamically modify the querybuilder inside a formbuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two possible alternatives.

If the request comes from the form itself (i.e. you already submitted the form with some data and want to refine the fields) you can access the submitted data like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $data = $builder->getData();
    // now you can access form data
```

If the request comes from another source, you should use the "options" parameter. First, build a new $option for the requested **user**:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'user' => null,
    ));
}
```

*Note: I set the default to null but you can set it to whatever you want.*

After that you can **pass** the $option where you build the form, i.e.

```
// some controller
$option = array('user' => $request->get('user');
$teamForm = $this->createForm(new TeamType(), null, $options);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks; that's another method; which seems lighter. worth a try! cheers

Comment: @Raphael_b happy to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer...

The best solution I found is create a variable in the formtype and to import it form the controller. My formType will look like that:

```
class formType extends AbstractType
{
    // declare and construct the query in the class  to use it in the function
    private $qb; 
    public function __construct ($qb)
    {
        $this->qb = $qb;
    }
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // declare the variable within the function
        $qb = $this->qb;
        $builder
            ->add('content',    'textarea', array('required' => false))
            ->add('rosters',    'entity', array( 
                'class'    =>   'PlatformBundle:Team',
                // use ($qb) -> $qb is query built in the controller (or repository) 
                'query_builder' => function(TeamRepository $r) use ($qb) {
                    return $qb;
                },
                'property' =>   'display',
                'multiple' =>   true,
                'expanded' =>   true,
                'required' =>   true
            ))
            ->add('send',       'submit');
    }
```

In my controller I just pass $qb as an argument of the formtype

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PlatformBundle:Team')->qbteam($Id);

        $form = $this->createForm(new formType($qb), $form);
```

with qbteam a function in the team repository which return the query (not a result).

```
public function qbteam($Id){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->leftJoin('r.team', 'm')
        ->addSelect('m')
        ->where('m.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $Id);
    return $qb; 
}
```

I hope it will help others.
cheers